# Parsing output from FindHamiltonianCycle to recover an ordered list of vertex positions for a discovered path

Tags: graphs-and-networks

After applying `FindHamiltonianCycle` to a graph, one generates output that looks like the following:

```
{{1<->2,2<->3,3<->4,4<->5,5<->6,6<->7,7<->8,8<->9,9<->10,10<->11,11<->12,12<->13,13<->14,14<->15,15<->16,16<->17,17<->18,18<->19,19<->20,20<->21,21<->22,<<3670>>,77<->75,75<->73,73<->71,71<->69,69<->67,67<->65,65<->63,63<->61,61<->59,59<->57,57<->55,55<->53,53<->51,51<->49,49<->47,47<->45,45<->43,43<->41,41<->39,39<->36,36<->1}}
```

I've replaced `\[UndirectedEdge]` with "<->" here to deal with formatting.

How can I quickly return an ordered list of vertices in the path, and an ordered list of their (previously specified) coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since vertices in `VertexCoordinates` are listed according to the graphs own vertex order (that is not necessarily `{1, 2, ..., n}`), it is safer to extract `VertexList` also to make the *node* $\rightarrow$ *coordinate* replacement.

```
g = Graph@{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1}
coord = VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions@g;
nodes = VertexList@g;
FindHamiltonianCycle[g, All]
pathNodes = Map[First, FindHamiltonianCycle[g], {2}]

(* ==>    {{1, 2, 3, 4}} *)
```

You can replace vertices with coordinates:

```
pathNodes /. Thread[nodes -> coord]
```